# Global asax split up

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently inherited a web site that has an odd setup for the global.asax file.  The site has a Global.asax file in the root and then the Global.asax.cs file in the App_Code folder.  All that's in the .asax file is:

```
<%@ Application Inherits="Global" Language="C#" %>
```

And then in the .asax.cs file we have some actual logic.  The code is definitely being hit, but not consistently so we're trying to pin down if the problem is that the files are in separate folders.

I'm not sure if I should combine the files, so that the .asax is actually inheriting the .asax.cs file.  Also, should I put these in the App_Code folder or at the root?

This site was built a while ago, so it's been added to and changed by multiple hands and I'm not sure what, if any, justification there was for putting the template file in a separate place.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's a web site, you even said it in your question, and not a web project. So the .cs files need to go into the App_Code folder to be compiled.

Comment: Right, it's a web site, but what I'm wondering is if I even need the .asax file that's in the root at all.

Comment: They are tied together behind the scenes. And I'm almost positive you will get an exception and I think an HTTP exception if you remove the markup.

Comment: I assumed as much, and the bug we were getting is apparently coming from somewhere else, just thought this was a weird layout.  Thanks for the comment.